# QApplicaiton and QWidget are not recognized in below

Tags: python

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QWidget()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

QApplication and QWidget are not recognized in the above code written in PyQt5